# android universal image loader get Image with private/public secret key

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image loader to load images from server. But there is need to send private and public key along with Image URL to get the image from server. How to send private/public key along with URL to get image? OR How to send parameters in GET call using Universal Image Loader library  Currently I am doing this without any parameters which is working fine..

```
//ImageLoader
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    uInit();

    //ImageLoader Initialization
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext)); 
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() 
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();           

    String imgUrl = Commons.CURRENT_ACTIVE_PROFILE.getPhoto();
    imgUrl = Urls.base_url_without_app_keyword + imgUrl;        
    if(imgUrl!=null && !imgUrl.isEmpty())
        loadUserProfileImage(imgUrl); 

}

private void loadUserProfileImage(String imgUrl) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, userProfileImg, displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() 
    { 
         @Override
         public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                 FailReason failReason) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {


         }
     }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() 
     {
         @Override
         public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                 int total) {
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample url. from above code

Comment: Here is the public key = "5c5c3fb9285408a849c6189d01ae9b" and private key = "0dc107e69b" . I am able to get this image by simple image loading methods using HttpConnection GET method by giving these keys as parameters but i dont know how to send these keys when getting image using ImageLoader library

Comment: can you post also the `HttpConnection` code you did

Comment: DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
  client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1),new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ProfileKey, ProfileSecret));
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

Comment: Sorry the above url image may be deleted from server side. This is working url: http://www.expecting-your-call.com/app/file/5/aba2663246fa360654123b6ab691d6e7/5c5c3fb9285408a849c6189d01ae9b.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "extra for downloader" for that purpose. and pass key in header

```
Map<String, String> headers = ...
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    ...
    .extraForDownloader(headers)
    ...
    .build();
```

Then create your own  ImageDownloader which handles these headers:

Refer this link https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/340

Hope it will help...